# htaccess rewrite problem when % symbol is used

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

We have an old forum that used VBSeo and the forum in particular we're trying to redirect for xenforo has an @ symbol in it, so "title of @ forum" forum title, and vbseo had linked it as "/forums/title-%40-forum/"

I tried making a physical folder called "/forums/title-%40-forum/" and it doesnt get found by browser.

I've also tried a pure 301 redirect no rewrite and it also is ignored because of the % symbol.

Is there a rewrite where i could successfully rewrite /forums/title-%40-forum/*   to a php file for parsing and redirecting to new url?

Comment: Could you please do mention sample URLs like from which URL to which URL you want to rewrite in your question for better understanding of your question.